# Roll dice program - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dice

I'm writing a program that will roll any number of dice, with any number of sides, any number of times. I'm stuck in my function that rolls the dice a number of times and then replaces the zeros in the list with the roll. I keep on getting an error on `rolls[rv]+=1`:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

My `ctrList` function that I sent to rolls, does return a list and I have tried changing that list into an `int` or `str` in my `rollSim` function, but nothing seems to work. Maybe I am going about this problem in the wrong way? Here is the code I have for this area so far:

```
numDice=int(input("How many dice do you want to roll? "))
numSides=int(input("How many Sides does each have? "))
numRolls=int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? "))


def ctrList(numSides, numDice): #Function that seeds  list with all zeros
    L=[]
    ctr=0
    possible= ((numSides * numDice)+1)
    for p in range (possible):
        ctr+=1
        L.append(0)
    return L

def rollSim(numDice, numSides, numRolls, rollDice):    

    rolls=ctrList(numSides, numDice) 
    for i in range (numRolls):
        rv= rollDice(numDice, numSides )
        rolls[rv]+=1        #where I keep on getting the error at :(
    return rolls

def rollDice(numDice, numSides ): #Function that rolls dice
    L=[]
    ctr=0
    for dice in range (numDice):
         L.append (random.randint(1, numSides))
         ctr+=1
    return L
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of rv directly to the command line?  It does not appear that rv is an integer so python cannot use it as an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems that instead of:

```
for i in range (numRolls):
    rv= rollDice(numDice, numSides )
    rolls[rv]+=1        #where I keep on getting the error at :(
```

you need:

```
for i in range (numRolls):
    rv = rollDice(numDice, numSides)
    for dice in rv:
        rolls[dice] += 1
```

Your `rollDice` returns results for `numDice` dices (a `list`). Then you try to index the `rolls` list with another list, which doesn't make any sense (and that's what the error is saying exactly).

You can also change the method to return only one result, for one dice:

```
def rollDice(numSides):
    return random.randint(1, numSides)
```

So your version of counting code will work. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your rollDice function returns a list, so when you do

```
rv = rollDice(numDice, numSides)
```

You assign a list to rv. You can't do rolls[rv] from there, rv needs to be an int.